# How can I install a new patio door where overhead framing obstructs access?

Tags: framing, patio, sliding-glass-door

I am getting ready to replace a window and install a patio door to the outside which has a covered patio. However, the top of the window, roughly where the top of the patio door will fit, will be very tight. I am hoping to make it work.

However, in the eventuality that it is simply too tight, what would be my options? Any advise would be appreciated.

One thought is to brace a portion of the patio roof (during installation) and then cut back the joists as noted in the attached image, then put everything back as before and sister/brace the joists and replace the piece 2x6 supporting the joists.

[image]

Comment: If that roof weren't there, how tall is the wall into which you're installing this door? i.e. will the door actually fit in the wall itself without running into the top plate? Also, what's above this on the wall? An opening that wide is going to need some sort of header above it to carry the load across the span where there were studs. This sliding door won't carry the roof load.

Comment: @FreeMan, right above that window there is about 12" of space (in the interior), the plan is that I will have a built-up 2-2x12 header inside that wall with a RO of 72"x80" .. header will be at the top-plate (no cripples). I am not sure why the patio roof was built this way, but it is what I am working with, those lag-bolts seen in the picture will most likely be driving into the new header behind it.

Comment: Huh... Once installed with that rim joist be over the door, or will the door be below it? You might be better off (looks wise, at least) planning on replacing the joists instead of sistering them. At a minimum, it would look funny and you'll be in and out there all the time. If not sistered correctly, it could start to sag and possibly collapse.

Comment: I think i will take you advise there to replace the joists once finished ... from the patio floor to the rim-joist is 83", the door (without the bottom screw fin, which i will likely cut off) will be 81" ... with the bottom plate (which I think i may leave intact) and other adjustments, this leaves me very little room to work above the door, eg. expose sufficient space to rework the stucco, add additional building paper, etc.

Comment: I guess I am looking for if my above "thought/idea" would work and if there are any pitfalls i may not be considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I cut the patio joists as outlined above and braced the area with a temporary wall. After the patio-door was complete, I braced the entire 16ft joist with new 2x6 boards and used double-width hangers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm still not clear why that was necessary. Any rough opening should have enough of a gap that you can simply start the top jamb first, then swing the bottom into position.

Comment: That head member is extremely tight, if it sags at all you're going to have issues.

Comment: it is possible that I could have gotten away without removing that section, in retrospect; i should have tried it first without removal and then only removed the section if needed (live and learn) :-)

Comment: Behind this section is a built-up 2-2x12 header, the lag-bolts (7x) penetrate the header behind ... I will keep an eye-out for sag.